# Why is Text After Image, Not Inline (React) + Why Won't Hover Line Appear?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navbar

Currently trying (and failing) to learn React for a project, and not understanding why the header links appear after the image, if they're in the same wrapper. I made different components for different parts of the navbar, and made a different file for the Logo and NavLinks (each in its own section). Here's the code.

**App.js**

```
// Importing NavBar
import NavBar from './components/navbar/NavBar';



// Actual App function, has our code
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
    {/* Navbar Declaration, with statement of what links to add */}
      <NavBar />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**NavBar.js**

```
// Importing react
import React from "react";
// Importing styled to be able to style the page
import styled from "styled-components";
// Importing the logo
import Logo from "../logo/Logo";
// Importing the links
import NavLinks from "./NavLinks.js";

// ---------------------------- Stylizing the navbar using styled-components

// Main Wrapper for Navbar
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1.5 rem;
    transition: background-color .5s ease;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.05);
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
`;

// NavBar is separated into left, center and right

// Left side of Navbar
const LeftSide = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;

// Center of Navbar
// Flex is a way to define how much each portion is gonna take of the size given to it
const Center = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;

// Right side of Navbar
const RightSide = styled.div`
    display: flex;
`;

// Declaration of navbar links
const navbarLinks = [
    "Home Page",
    "Illustrator Gallery",
    "Art Gallery",
    "Challenges"
];

/*const navbarLinks = [
    { title: `Home Page`, path: `/` },
    { title: `Illustrator Gallery`, path: `/illustrator-gallery` },
    { title: `Art Gallery`, path: `/art-gallery` },
    { title: `Challenges`, path: `/challenges` }
];*/

// ---------------------------- Creating the NavBar function/component
function NavBar(props) {
    // Setting the return value, or the component
    return(
        <Wrapper>
            {/* For the left side, we want to import the Logo component */}
            <LeftSide>
                <Logo />
            </LeftSide>

            <Center>
                {/* For the middle, we want to add the different links */}
                <NavLinks links={navbarLinks} />
            </Center>

            <RightSide></RightSide>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

**Logo.js**

```
// Importing react
import React from 'react';
// Importing styled components
import styled from "styled-components";
// Importing the image
import USLogo from "../../assets/images/bunny.png"

// Styling the wrapper for the logo
const LogoWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`;

// Styling the actual logo, as well as its container
const LogoImg = styled.div`
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
`;

// Styling the information next to the logo
const LogoText = styled.h2`
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: black;
`;

// Creating logo
function Logo(props) {
    return(
        // First we make the wrapper
        <LogoWrapper>
            {/* Inside the wrapper we'll have the image, then the text */}
            <LogoImg><img src={USLogo} alt="US. logo"/></LogoImg>
            <LogoText>US.</LogoText>
        </LogoWrapper>
    );
}

export default Logo;
```

**NavLinks.js**

```
// Importing react
import React from 'react';
// Importing styling
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Styling the container for the links
const LinksContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`;

// Styling the ul components, or the menu
const LinksMenu = styled.ul`
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
`;

// Styling each li
const LinksItem = styled.li`
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 0 1.1rem;
`;

// Styling each link 
const Link = styled.a`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin: 0 2rem;
    position: relative;

    &:hover{
        color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
    }

    &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -3px;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
        transition transform .5s ease;
    }

    &:hover::after{
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
`;

// Creating the navigation links component
function NavLinks(props) {
    return(
        // First we do the container
        <LinksContainer>
        {/* Inside the container, we have the menu of links, then the li, and finally links */}
            <LinksMenu>
            {/* Each link Menu has a bunch of items, with each item having a link */}
                {
                    props.links.map(
                        (label) => {
                            return(
                                <LinksItem><Link>{label}</Link></LinksItem>
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            </LinksMenu>
        </LinksContainer>
    );
}

export default NavLinks;
```

The result shows as follows:

[image: Image of the problem]

Additionally, if I hover over the text, it doesn't change anything. In fact, it doesn't even add the little blue color indicating it's a link anymore. I'm not sure if this is a syntactical problem, since the same code works fine when using css.

I've checked other answers on here suggesting `float: left` and the like for the wrapper, but for some reason they don't work. Either I'm putting them in the wrong object, or they should be somewhere else.

Any help is appreciated!